# Unable to share Excel workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion, file-sharing, office365, xml

I have run across an issue with Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus.

I have an Excel workbook with multiple pages to be shared among multiple users within a work group at one time. When I go to Review - Share Workbook (Legacy), I receive the following error message:

> This workbook cannot be shared because it contains Excel tables or XML maps.

I then go to Design - Tools tab to convert to Range and there aren't any tables within the workbook that needs to be converted.
I then go to Developer - Source to remove XML maps , and there aren't any to be removed.

What must I do to be able to share the workbook?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a new workbook
2. Share the new workbook
3. Copy all the data from the original workbook to the new workbook.

You can try copying entire sheets to preserve everything. If that doesn't work you will have to select all, copy, and paste sheet data one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the list below. At least one of the unsupported items must be the culprit.

*<sub>From [support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/About-the-shared-workbook-feature-49b833c0-873b-48d8-8bf2-c1c59a628534?CTT=1&CorrelationId=24c8a932-ffbd-493f-b56e-10cf26aaf79c&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HP010342985):</sub>*

> Shared Workbooks have limitations, and therefore we highly recommend
>   [co-authoring](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/coauthoring-7152aa8b-b791-414c-a3bb-3024e46fb104), which is the replacement for Shared Workbooks.
>
> Please be aware that Shared Workbooks is an older method of sharing.
>   Therefore, many items and actions are not supported when this method
>   is used. ***The table below is only a partial list of features not
>   supported.***
>
> ### **Unsupported items:**
>
> - Creating or inserting tables
> - Adding or changing conditional formats
> - Adding or changing data validation
> - Creating or changing charts or PivotChart reports
> - Inserting or changing pictures or other objects
> - Inserting or changing hyperlinks
> - Creating, changing, or viewing scenarios
> - Inserting automatic subtotals
> - Creating data tables
> - Creating or changing PivotTable reports
> - Creating or applying slicers
> - Creating or modifying sparklines
> - Adding or changing Microsoft Excel 4 dialog sheets
> - Importing, refreshing, and exporting XML data
>
> ### **Unsupported actions:**
>
> - Inserting or deleting blocks of cells
> - Deleting worksheets
> - Merging cells or splitting merged cells
> - Sorting or filtering by format
> - Using drawing tools
> - Assigning, changing, or removing passwords
> - Protecting or unprotecting worksheets or the workbook
> - Grouping or outlining data
> - Writing, recording, changing, viewing, or assigning macros
> - Changing or deleting array formulas
> - Adding, renaming, or deleting XML maps
> - Mapping cells to XML elements
> - Using the XML Source task pane, XML toolbar, or XML commands on the    Data menu
> - Using a data form to add new data